# Transacciones con codeigniter con múltiples verificaciones

Tags: php, codeigniter, transacciones

Estoy trabajando en el registro de una transacción en la que tengo que hacer un llamado a la función `enviarDinero` en una api externa la cual solo retorna el id de la transacción en el sistema externo o false. *(no hay forma de revertir esta operación)*

En mi sistema tengo una tabla con un registro que se debe modificar cuando la llamada a la función `enviarDinero` sea exitosa.

Entonces plantee esta solución con posibles fallos:

```
    $transaccion_id = 453;
    $monto = 53.5;
    $destino = "usuariox";
    $result = $this->apiexterna->enviarDinero($destino,$monto); 
   /*
    * Parte critica, si el sistema se apaga no habrá ningún registro en la base de datos 
    * de la operacion a la api externa.
    */
    if(!$result) return FALSE;
    $data = array("external_transaccion_id", $result);
    $this->where("transaccion_id",$transaccion_id);
    $this->update("transacciones", $data);
```

Luego se me ocurrió poner una bandera en la base para que quede al menos un registro de que la operación se intento y que posiblemente se envió el dinero.

```
 $this->db->trans_begin();        

$data_update_complete = array("intento"=>1, "fecha_intento"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

    $this->where("transaccion_id",$transaccion_id);
    $this->update("transacciones", $data_update_complete);

    /*ESTO ES CORRECTO????????*/
     if ($this->db->trans_status() === false) {
         $this->db->trans_rollback();
         return FALSE;
     }

    $transaccion_id = 453;
    $monto = 53.5;
    $destino = "usuariox";
    $result = $this->apiexterna->enviarDinero($destino,$monto); 

   /*
    * Parte critica, si el sistema se apaga el no habra ningun registro en la base de datos 
    * de la operacion a la api externa.
    */
    if(!$result) return FALSE;
    $data = array("external_transaccion_id", $result);
    $this->where("transaccion_id",$transaccion_id);
    $this->update("transacciones", $data)

if ($this->db->trans_status() === false) {
    /* DES HACER LOS CAMBIOS EN LA BASE SI FALLA LA TRANSACCIÓN */
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
    return FALLSE;
} else {
    /*  CONFIRMAR CAMBIOS EN LA BASE */
    $this->db->trans_commit();
    return TRUE;
}
```

Es correcto utilizar `$this->db->trans_status()` más de una vez en codeigniter?

¿Hay alguna forma mas elegante de resolver este problema?

Comment: No es incorrecto hacer uso de `trans_status()` en la documentación oficial de codeigniter hacen uso de el de la misma manera en la que tu lo estas haciendo, excepto por el uso de `return FALSE;` que en tu caso lo tienes con doble LL (`return FALLSE`).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me pregunto cual de las 2 es lo correcto, si utilizar $this->db->affected_rows(); para validar que se realizaron los update o inserts o trans_status()

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo el ejemplo de una transacción manual que esta en la [documentación](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html) de `codeigniter`, usted puede realizar un seguimiento de sus consultas y determinar si debe confirmar`trans_commit()` o anular`trans_rollback()` en función del éxito`TRUE` o el fracaso`FALSE` de sus consultas.

> Puede ejecutar tantas consultas como desee entre las funciones de
>   inicio/completar y todas se confirmarán o anularán en función del
>   éxito o el fracaso de una consulta determinada.

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
        $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

Lo que hace `$this->db->affected_rows();` es mostrar el número de filas afectadas, cuando se realizan consultas de tipo "escritura" (insertar, actualizar, etc.). Pero básicamente si existe algún fallo en la consulta o algo parecido lo identificaras con el `status`.